# Using ARIMA to predict non-complete period

Tags: r, time-series, arima

I'm trying to use ARIMA (R-language implementation) and forecast daily data.
The initial data set contains per-hour values for 15 days and model is built like

```
myModel<-arima (knownData, order=c(24, 1, 24),include.mean=FALSE,method="CSS")
```

Predicting next 24 values (next day) works nice - data is very close to reality (including time structure, minimum and maximum are where they really are).

Now I won't to predict the end of the day, based on the beginning:

```
newModel<-Arima(additionalData,model=myModel)
newForecast<-predict(newModel, n.ahead=24)
```

Where `additionalData` contains about 12 values. The result is awful, not even close to what it should be.

**Question**

It's obvious, that I'm doing something wrong, but not sure what exactly - either model is bad, or data is used improperly, or something else.

**Values**

Daily forecast data (very close to real data structure and values):

```
1.5381624  6.4080989 19.8963887 31.0804878 24.5755121 35.7171803 36.3545548 37.4275811 36.8051448 34.6626951 23.7145071 32.4005010      31.6820914 35.8199186 39.2482743 47.7286449 40.5614604 45.2695602 36.1903594 30.3068764 23.3358931 13.1883880 -0.4366872  6.1197422
```

Second forecast, after adding 13 more values:

```
-10.749518 -23.843293 -21.503110  -1.098214  16.500469  34.364534  55.129484  67.012708  79.486753  73.354853  62.377744
```

Negative values, instead of relatively big positive and no minimum at the end.

Comment: AR and MA orders of 24 look pretty high. Perhaps you should reduce the AR and MA orders and use some seasonal dummies or Fourier terms instead, or a seasonal ARIMA model. How much data do you have? Are you sure the first model does a good job in forecasting? Might that be a mistake or a coincidence? If you have a lot of data, adding 12 observations should not change the estimated model by much (you can compare the estimated coefficients). Also, function `Arima` does not have an argument `model`. If you supply it and the function does not give you an error that does not mean it works OK.

Comment: Also, if the first model was really good and the new day is not an outlier, forecasting 36 steps ahead using the old model could still work fine as compared with forecasting 24 steps ahead using a model estimated on a 12-observations longer sample. I mean, instead of adding new data to reestimate the model and forecast for a shorter horizon, why not use the old model and a longer forecasting horizon.

Comment: @RichardHardy Thank you for the reply,  '?Arima' - shows, it's a wrapper for 'arima', last argument is 'model'. 24 depth to cover the whole day. Anyway, I suddenly understood that the point is in forecasting and the answer on my question "What's wrong?" is in forecasting mechanism - it  may use coefficients in non-trivial way, or simply not as I think it does.

Comment: My bad, function `Arima` indeed has an argument `model`. I don't know how I managed to miss it. Regarding your recent comment, I don't quite get what could be wrong with forecasting *given a good model*. The forecasting mechanism due to an ARIMA model is pretty simple (in my opinion), so there should be no misuse of coefficients in non-trivial ways. I still am suspicious of the high AR and MA orders. Your argument for covering the whole day is intuitive but still you will need a very large sample to estimate an ARIMA(24,1,24) model with any precision and reliability.

Comment: However, there is still this puzzle that you get accurate forecasts from the initial model on the initial period but poor forecasts when you move 12 observations ahead (still using the same model as I now understand). If you answered the questions from my first comment, maybe it would become clearer.